# Memory leak in SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider?

Tags: 2010, 2013, memory-leak

while playing with custom claims provider I've found interesting thing in `SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider`. If you investigate a code using any .net assembly browser\decompiler (.NET Reflector or ILSpy) you will find a memory leak of `SPWeb` object in method `FillResolve`. Take a closer look at the code:

```
// Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider
private void FillResolve(Uri context, string[] entityTypes, bool inputIsEmailOnly, string resolveInput, List<PickerEntity> resolved)
{
    SPWeb sPWeb = null;
    SPSite sPSite = null;
    if (!SPThreadContext.Items.Contains("SPActiveDirectoryClaimProviderIgnoreContext"))
    {
        bool catchAccessDeniedException = SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
            sPSite = new SPSite(context.AbsoluteUri);
            if (sPSite != null)
            {
                sPWeb = sPSite.OpenWeb();
            }
            if (!sPWeb.Exists)
            {
                sPWeb = null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if (sPSite != null)
            {
                sPSite.Dispose();
                sPWeb = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = catchAccessDeniedException;
        }
    }
    try
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(context);
        SPPrincipalType scopes = SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.ConvertEntityTypeToPrincipalTypes(entityTypes);
        SPPrincipalInfo sPPrincipalInfo = SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal(sPWeb, webApp, resolveInput, scopes, inputIsEmailOnly);
        if (sPPrincipalInfo != null)
        {
            if (inputIsEmailOnly && MatchType.EmailAddress == sPPrincipalInfo.MatchType && SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.DisableEmailResolve())
            {
                ULS.SendTraceTag(2466693u, ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ClaimsAuthentication, ULSTraceLevel.VerboseEx, "Dicarding match '{0}' for input '{1}' because it is email match and feature is disabled.", new object[]
                {
                    sPPrincipalInfo.LoginName,
                    resolveInput
                });
            }
            else
            {
                PickerEntity pickerEntity = this.CreatePickerEntity(sPPrincipalInfo);
                if (pickerEntity != null)
                {
                    resolved.Add(pickerEntity);
                    ULS.SendTraceTag(1634481712u, ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ClaimsAuthentication, ULSTraceLevel.VerboseEx, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Returning AD resolve match '{0}' for input '{1}'.", new object[]
                    {
                        pickerEntity.Key,
                        resolveInput
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!inputIsEmailOnly)
            {
                int maxCount = 10;
                bool flag = false;
                IList<SPPrincipalInfo> list;
                if (sPWeb != null)
                {
                    list = SPUtility.SearchPrincipals(sPWeb, resolveInput, scopes, SPPrincipalSource.Windows, null, maxCount, out flag);
                }
                else
                {
                    list = SPUtility.SearchWindowsPrincipals(webApp, resolveInput, scopes, maxCount, out flag);
                }
                List<PickerEntity> list2 = new List<PickerEntity>();
                foreach (SPPrincipalInfo current in list)
                {
                    if (inputIsEmailOnly && MatchType.EmailAddress == current.MatchType && SPActiveDirectoryClaimProvider.DisableEmailResolve())
                    {
                        ULS.SendTraceTag(2466694u, ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ClaimsAuthentication, ULSTraceLevel.VerboseEx, "Dicarding match '{0}' for input '{1}' because it is email match and feature is disabled.", new object[]
                        {
                            current.LoginName,
                            resolveInput
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PickerEntity pickerEntity2 = this.CreatePickerEntity(current);
                        if (pickerEntity2 != null)
                        {
                            list2.Add(pickerEntity2);
                            ULS.SendTraceTag(1634481713u, ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ClaimsAuthentication, ULSTraceLevel.VerboseEx, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Returning AD resolve search match '{0}' for input '{1}'.", new object[]
                            {
                                pickerEntity2.Key,
                                resolveInput
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (list2.Count == 1 && list2[0].Claim != null && SPClaim.EqualClaimValues(list2[0].Claim.Value, resolveInput))
                {
                    resolved.Add(list2[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (list2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        PickerEntity pickerEntity = base.CreatePickerEntity();
                        pickerEntity.IsResolved = false;
                        pickerEntity.DisplayText = resolveInput;
                        pickerEntity.MultipleMatches.AddRange(list2);
                        resolved.Add(pickerEntity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sPSite != null)
        {
            sPSite.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

According to the best practice (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557362%28v=office.14%29.aspx) we should dispose `SPWeb` objects that were created using `OpenWeb` method. But `sPWeb` object is not disposed in any part of the method. It means, that every time we perform search and resolve in people picker, one `SPWeb` object will be leaked. I don't have msdn subscription in order to contact Microsoft regarding this problem. This issue is true for SharePoint 2010 (SP2) and SharePoint 2013 (SP1).

I believe community can confirm memory leak and contact Microsoft to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling Dispose() on the SPSite that the OpenWeb method was used on will automatically dispose of the SPWeb it opened.  As long as the SPSite is being disposed of, you won't have issues here unless you are opening a ton of SPWeb's and not disposing them explicitly.

Looking at that code, it appears to be disposing of the SPSite, so it should be fine.

**EDIT**

For reference, here is the .Close() method from the SPSite class called by the .Dispose() method.  As you can see, it disposed of any SPWebs it opened before disposing itself:

```
public void Close()
{
    SPEventManager.WaitForPostEvents();
    if (this.m_openedWebs != null)
    {
        SPWeakObjectHandleList<SPWeb> list = new SPWeakObjectHandleList<SPWeb>(this.m_openedWebs);
        foreach (SPWeb web in list)
        {
            web.Close();
        }
        list.Dispose();
        this.m_openedWebs.Dispose();
    }
    this.m_rootWebCreated = false;
    SPRequestContext.UnregisterSite(this);
    this.InvalidateSite();
}
```

Comment: BTW there are a LOT of false-positive memory leaks reported by these tools on the SharePoint assemblies.

Comment: I completely disagree with you. When using spsite and spweb (that was created using `OpenWeb`) you should dispose **both** spweb and spsite. Take a look at the msdn best practice - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557362%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  They always dispose spweb **and** spsite in every sample regarding `OpenWeb`. Could you please provide msdn article or any proof link were described, that you can not dispose spweb, that was created using `OpenWeb`?

Comment: I agree, you **should** dispose the SPWebs, but you don't **have** to.  Particularly if you are just opening one or two SPWebs.  If you open Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in .NET Reflector, look at the .Close() method on the SPSite class (this is called by Dispose()).  It disposes of any open SPWebs that it had opened before disposing.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the SPSite.Close() method.

Comment: Now I see.. It's a bit shocking after 3+ years of disposing objects :) It seems, I can mark your answer as completed. Thanks for edit!

Comment: HA!  Yes, still good practice.  There are a few bloggers out there who thing it's unnecessary (for SPSites and SPWebs), but tend to stay on the safer side and dispose everything.